# Composite c1 in Load Balanced Environment

Tags: c1-cms

I’ve just complete evaluating CMS systems and am about to select Composite C1, but I need a solution that I can scale out and load-balance, primarily for redundancy. I’m looking to clarify the challenges and solution recommendations associated with load-balancing a Composite C1 solution with a SQL Server provider.

Also, my current requirements are for an on-premise solution (so the Windows Azure approach is off the table for now).

What issues / challenges need to be addressed with Composite C1 scale out?  So far my understanding is the following:

1. Cache Synchronization across load balanced servers. 
   It doesn’t appear that there is any mechanism available to automatically handle cache expiration across servers related to content updates and associated publishing. As a result, only the server that receiving the publish request the request would expire it’s content cache. How can I easily and reliably handle this across the farm, without requiring developer or operations intervention?
2. File System Synchronization across load balanced servers.
   This would handle changes to the file system that might be caused by adding/deleting/changing dataypes, or modifying templates, etc. Composite.Generated.dll
3. Console Architecture
   Should the console be an all servers in the farm? Should the console even be in the load balanced environment?
4. Am I correct in assuming that SQL Server is better than XML storage for this configuration?
5. What else do I need to consider / address?

Answer (score 0):

FYI: The questions you asked have been answered here: https://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/456286